# Basic inequality on a floor function (Proof verification).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $a_n=n/c$ be a real sequence with $n>c\geq 1$ constant. I am inspecting if the following (surprising) result holds:
$$\bigg\lvert \frac{1}{\left \lfloor{a_n}\right \rfloor }-\frac{1}{a_n}\bigg\rvert\leq \frac{C}{n^2}, \quad \text{ for some }C>0 \text{ and all } n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Could you please check if my proof is acceptable?

**My attempt**

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}:n>1$. Then
\begin{align}
a_n-1<\left \lfloor{a_n}\right \rfloor\leq a_n\iff \frac{1}{a_n-1}-\frac{1}{a_n}>\frac{1}{\left \lfloor{a_n}\right \rfloor }-\frac{1}{a_n}\geq 0.
\end{align}

By definition 
$$\frac{1}{a_n-1}-\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{c^2}{n^2-cn}.$$
But the following sequence converges,
$$\frac{c^2}{n^2-cn}n^2=\frac{c^2}{1-c/n}\to c^2 \text{ as } n\to\infty,$$
and so it is bounded by, say, $M>0$ (for all $n$). From these facts, we have
$$\frac{1}{\left \lfloor{a_n}\right \rfloor }-\frac{1}{a_n}<\frac{M}{n^2}.$$
Identifying $M=C$, we are done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When $n$ is very large, then $1/\lfloor c/n \rfloor$ is not defined.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks. I wrote it wrong. A little detail that makes great difference. It is $a_n=n/c$

Comment: How can you conclude "for all $n \in \mathbb N$" when your hypothesis says "$n>c\geq 1$"?

Comment: Ok, I changed to $n>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is not quite correct. The issue is that for $n \lt c$ you get in those cases, as [angryavian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43949/angryavian)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614943/basic-inequality-on-a-floor-function-proof-verification#comment7430350_3614943) has indicated for an earlier version of your question, that $\frac{1}{\lfloor n/c \rfloor}$ becomes $\frac{1}{0}$.

I believe the start of the problem with your proof is in your line of

$$a_n-1<\left \lfloor{a_n}\right \rfloor\leq a_n\iff \frac{1}{a_n-1}-\frac{1}{a_n}>\frac{1}{\left \lfloor{a_n}\right \rfloor }-\frac{1}{a_n}\geq 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The issue is it implicitly assumes that $a_n - 1 \gt 0 \iff a_n \gt 1$.

One way to handle this is to add to your statement of

$$\bigg\lvert \frac{1}{\left \lfloor{a_n}\right \rfloor }-\frac{1}{a_n}\bigg\rvert\leq \frac{C}{n^2}, \quad \text{ for some }C>0 \text{ and all } n\in\mathbb{N} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

something like "$\text{ where } n \ge c$". Also, in your proof, you can add mention that the case where $n = c$, so $a_n = 1$, is true as the LHS of your statement becomes $0$. Then, with your proof technique, as I stated above, can handle all of the remaining cases where $a_n \gt 1$.

Comment: Indeed, I will add more details.

Comment: In the problem I'm handling, the positive constant $c$ needs to be greater than 1.

Comment: @CelineHarumi That's not sufficient. For example, if $c = 2$, then for $n = 1$, you get $a_1 = 1/2$, so $\lfloor a_1 \rfloor = 0$ and, thus, $1/\lfloor a_1 \rfloor = 1/0$, which is not valid. Instead, you do need to have something else, with my suggestion of $n \gt c$ being the simplest one I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The assumption that $n>c$ also holds for my specific case. Did you see any other problem with the rest of the proof?

Comment: @CelineHarumi You're welcome. Apart from that one issue, everything else looks correct.

Comment: @CelineHarumi Also, note I should have stated $n \ge c$ instead of $n \gt c$, so I also made a small mistake as well. I'm sorry about that. However, I've now corrected that in my answer.